# Send a image from android via Post method to PHP and save it in server?

Tags: php, android, kotlin, plesk

I am written an android app that should send profile images to server and save it there ...
I am using gotev android upload service and it works well and send my image to server , but my problem is in my server side that can't move or copy of it in my destination folder ...
my PHP in my server is :

```
<?php 
$isSuccess = false ;
$uploaddir = 'profiles/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['profile']['name']);

if ($_FILES["profile"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["profile"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
    $myObj->name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
    $myObj->type = $_FILES['profile']['type'];
    $myObj->size = ($_FILES["profile"]["size"] / 1024);
    $myObj->storedin = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];
    $myObj->username = $_POST['username'];
    if(isset($_FILES['profile']['name']) && isset($_POST['username'])){
        try{
            copy($_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'],$uploadfile );
            //$movesuc = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'],$uploadfile);
            //$myObj->mvesuc = $movesuc;
            $myObj->error = false;
            $isSuccess = true;
            $myObj->message = 'File uploaded successfully';
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $myObj->error = true;
            $myObj->message = 'Could not upload file';
        }
    }else{
        $myObj->error = true;
        $myObj->message = "Required params not available";
    }
}
//header('Content-Type: application/json');
$myObj->isSuccess = $isSuccess;
$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
echo $myJSON;
```

Comment: @ken-lee I try it but it doesn't work again ... i don't know , maybe i should get access to my PHP file to can move or copy file in my host server

Comment: is this folder in the host server writable ?

Comment: @ken-lee yeah , the problem is folder permission that i can't write on it ... i changed it and now it work ... thanks

Comment: Great ! Have a nice day.